# JComboBox from swingx

Tags: java, swing, jcombobox, swingx

How do I use JComboBox (strict or non-strict) from `swingx`? Can somebody post a simple example or tutorial? http://swingx.java.net/

Answer (score -2, accepted):

SwingX components extend their `JComponent` counterparts and can be added as any other `JComponent` (like using the `addComponent(....)` method).
If you are using NetBeans IDE 7.0 (or earlier) you can copy the class of the `JXComboBox` to the package you are using and then drag-and-drop as if you are adding from a palette.

Comment: -1 for spreading incorrect rumors: SwingX is _not at all_ deprecated (who should do that, anyway?). It's a well-maintained, widely used and active standalone open source project.

Comment: The edit actually made it a lot worse. Apparently, the OP said SwingX components were deprecated. Later he changed it to the current outrageous lie. Not all SwingX Components extend JPanel. Certainly JXComboBox doesn't. This is hogwash and should be deleted.

Comment: @MikeAdler it is the accepted answer. I didn't mean *all* SwingX components extend JPanel.

Comment: The accepted answer has been wrong all along. That's not much of an argument. Perhaps you didn't mean _all_ SwingX components extends JPanel, but that is very much the common understanding of what you wrote. In any case, your answer does not in fact answer the question, states wrong information as fact and has been substantially altered since having been accepted, which is always somewhat suspicious.

Answer (score 2):

Your question is:

### "How do I use the SwingX `AutoCompleteDecorator` for `J(X)ComboBoxes?`"

And the answer is:

"You can find example sourcecode for strict and non-strict JComboBoxes, JTextFields and a strict JTextField with a JList in the webstartable [SwingX-demo](http://swinglabs-demos.java.net/demos/swingxset6/swingxset.jnlp) from http://swingx.java.net/. Launch the demo, click the "Autocomplete Demo" entry in the tasklist section "Functionality" and you will see the examples and the "AutoCompleteDemo.java"-sourcecode."

Answer (score 0):

Swingx's JXComboBox doesn't add anything other than visual enhancements to the standard swing JComboBox. And JComboBox usage is well described, like all the other Swing components, in the [Swing tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/combobox.html).

Comment: That's just wrong. From the [javadoc](http://java.net/projects/swingx/sources/svn/content/trunk/swingx-core/src/main/java/org/jdesktop/swingx/JXComboBox.java): _"An enhanced `JComboBox` that provides the following additional functionality: 
Auto-starts edits correctly for AutoCompletion when inside a `JTable`. A normal `JComboBox` fails to recognize the first key stroke when it has been decorated. 
Adds highlighting support."_

Comment: Yes, that's what I mean by "visual enhancements". The API is identical to the one of JComboBox. See http://download.java.net/javadesktop/swinglabs/releases/0.8/docs/api/org/jdesktop/swingx/JXComboBox.html

Comment: You are referring (and linking) to an very old SwingX-0.8-version: it's from November 2005. There were _some_ releases since then: the newest is **[SwingX 1.6.4](http://java.net/downloads/swingx/releases/)**. In my first comment I already mentioned the link to [the class in java.net svn-repository](http://java.net/projects/swingx/sources/svn/content/trunk/swingx-core/src/main/java/org/jdesktop/swingx/JXComboBox.java).

Comment: Agreed. It's a pity such a project doesn't have a decent documentation site, where the API doc can be browsed (at least I didn't find any). Anyway, except for the highlighter-related methods that have been added, the API is still the same as JComboBox, and my answer still applies: you use a JXComboBox the same way as a JComboBox, and the best way to know how to use it is to read the Swing tutorial about JComboBox.

Comment: I disagree, nothing else, Document and Pattern can do that and for larger Arrays (number of elements), sure must be sorted before, drink and drugs are bad ....